# Return the score of a row based on if a column value is in a table

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am looking for a way to automate this process with VBA. Currently I am performing this "scoring" with helper cells (not VBA).

I am trying to score a row based on the contents of the values in it. If the value in that row is equal to a value in anyone of the defined tables, then it will follow a simple scoring rubric:

- Scent    = 7
- Pigment  = 6
- AO       = 5
- MC       = 4
- PPA      = 3
- Antistat = 2
- If the value is not located in a table, simply return a "1"

Scoring row_2, is detailed in row 3. The formula in cell A3 is:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(Scent,A2)>0,7,IF(COUNTIF(Pigment,A2)>0,6,IF(COUNTIF(AO,A2)>0,5,IF(COUNTIF(MT,A2)>0,4,IF(COUNTIF(PPA,A2)>0,3,IF(COUNTIF(Antistat,A2)>0,2,1))))))
```

Which returns the value of "7" because `M14301855` is a value that resides in the "scent" table.

Cell G3 is what actually details the "score" that the row receives. Which is "largest value"."2nd largest value":

```
=VALUE(LARGE(A3:F3,1)&"."&LARGE(A3:F3,2))
```

Which returns the value of "7.5" because the row has a "scent" match and an "AO" match.

I can perform this task successfully with helper cells, I am looking for a way to accomplish this with some VBA script. I imagine that this can be accomplished in one way or another with an array, but I am still learning VBA and am unsure how to proceed.
[image: Image of my current worksheet]
**THANK YOU IN ADVANCE FOR ANY HELP!**

Comment: Post excel doc or sample of it.

Comment: I posted a picture of what I have. I am unsure how to post the file I am working with. How would I do that? Thank you!

Comment: Can one lookup value be in the same table as another (i.e., could you get a score of 7.7)?

Answer (score 0):

An array formula should do it for you (confirm with `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter`):

```
=SUM(LARGE(CHOOSE({1,2,3,4,5,6},OR(A2:F2=Scent),OR(A2:F2=Pigment),OR(A2:F2=AO),OR(A2:F2=MC),OR(A2:F2=PPA),OR(A2:F2=Antistat))*{6,5,4,3,2,1}+1,{1,2})*{1,0.1})
```

Here's a breakdown:

1. Use `OR` to check if any of your values are in each table.
2. `CHOOSE` with `{1,2,3,4,5,6}` for the `index_num` argument the combines all the comparisons from step 1 into a single array.
3. Using `{1,2}` for the `k` argument in `LARGE` will return an array of the 2 largest values in the array from step 2.
4. Multiply the array from step 3 by `{1,0.1}` to put the second score in the tenths place.
5. Sum the array from step 4.

Note: I used `MC` for the MC table instead of `MT` like you had in your formula.

UPDATE: If your codes always follow the "M00000000" pattern and your tables are always all the same length, this formula is a little simpler (still confirm with `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter`):

```
=SUM(LARGE(IFERROR((FIND(A2:F2,Antistat&PPA&MC&AO&Pigment&Scent)+17)/9,1),{1,2})*{1,0.1})
```

If the tables aren't necessarily the same length, you could pad the bottom of them with e.g., M00000000.